# Investment Portfolio Analysis: Could you recommend software or a web application with these features?

Tags: investing, portfolio, software, online-applications, recommendation

I'm looking for software to track my various investments.  I have brokerage accounts at TDAmeritrade, Interactive Brokers and ShareBuilder (now part of ING).  I also have a 401K at ING.  What I'd like is a low cost way of:

1. Importing transactions from all accounts (I don't want to type my transactions in)
2. Doing basic analysis

   - Risk analysis
   - Portfolio optimization
   - Tax analysis
   - Sharpe ratio
3. Suggestions of what to buy to mitigate risk would be nice as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a free service that can import your portfolio from other brokerages and do basic analysis.  Head over to [Wikinvest](http://www.wikinvest.com)

Comment: I like Wikinvest, but it doesn't cover 2 out of 3 of my accounts (401k over which I have no control).

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be an off-shoot of Wikinvest, [Sig Fig](https://secure.sigfig.com/l/portfolio), does a better job of dealing with the Portfolio Optimization and Sharpe Ratio parts of the question.